# Crear host virtual para Laravel en xampp usando puerto 8003

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, windows, xampp, localhost

Estoy intentando crear un host virtual para mi proyecto en Laravel usando Xampp.

- Ya agregue `127.0.0.1       proyecto.com` en el archivo `hosts` de `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`
- Cambie el valor 80 por 8003 en el archivo `httpd.conf` de `C:\xampp\apache\conf`
- Agregue lo siguiente:

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/proyecto/public"
    ServerName proyecto.com
</VirtualHost>`

en el archivo `httpd-vhosts.conf` de `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra`

Cuando lo dejo todo con el puerto `80` si puedo acceder al proyecto con `proyecto.com`, pero cuando cambio todo por `8003` no carga, dice que no se puede acceder.

Comment: Que error en el especifíco te marca?

Comment: Solo me dice que no se puede acceder, lo mismo que me sale cuando apache no esta activado.

Comment: Perfecto, revisa que ese puerto que asignas, no esta ocupado por otro servicio, en la consola o terminal utiliza `netstat` me parece que ese comando funciona para todos los sistemas operativos. Si ese puerto en efecto esta libre sigue este [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port) puede ayudarte, es de la comunidad de stackoverflow en ingles

Comment: El puerto 8003 no esta ocupado, tampoco el 443. Lo raro es que con el 80 si funciona el host, cambio todo que diga 80 por 8003 y nada.

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80> cambialo a VirtualHost *:8003 y reinicia servicios.

Comment: Lo cambie a <VirtualHost *:8003> .Logre acceder a la url pero solo si coloco el puerto al final asi: proyecto.com:8003 ¿Hay forma de no tener que colocar el puerto al final de la url?